# Horizontal lines in a table cell as a part of a form

Tags: tables

I am trying to design a form in LaTeX, to be filled by hand. I need to replicate a form that is already being used elsewhere, as closely as possible. The said form uses horizontal lines to write on, inside a table cell, as shown below:

[image]

I tried using underscores(_) to generate the said line. Is there a more elegant method?
[image]

Here's the MWE.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}


\newcommand{\longline}{\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_}
\newcommand{\shortline}{\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_}
\newcommand{\mediumline}{\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_}

\newcommand{\ratings}{\_\_\_1~~~\_\_\_2~~~\_\_\_3~~~\_\_\_4}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{p{0.55\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.24\textwidth}}
    Subject Knowledge/ Conceptual Clarity   &\ratings & \multirow{4}{4.5cm}{{\textbf{Any specific comments on trainer}} \newline\newline \mediumline  \newline\newline \mediumline \newline\newline  \mediumline\newline\newline  \mediumline \newline\newline  }\\ [2\baselineskip]
    Trainer Created and maintained an environment for learning &\ratings & \\[2\baselineskip]
    Rate the trainer's training skills and competency &\ratings &\\ [2\baselineskip]
    Would you like to attend other sessions by this trainer &\ratings &
    \\[2\baselineskip]

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably using `\rule`s is better:

```
\newcommand{\mediumline}{\rule{0.24\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\newcommand{\ratingsline}{\rule{15pt}{0.4pt}}

\newcommand{\ratings}{\ratingsline 1~~~\ratingsline 2~~~\ratingsline 3~~~\ratingsline 4}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}


\newcommand{\mediumline}{\rule{0.24\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\newcommand{\ratingsline}{\rule{15pt}{0.4pt}}

\newcommand{\ratings}{\ratingsline 1~~~\ratingsline 2~~~\ratingsline 3~~~\ratingsline 4}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{p{0.55\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.24\textwidth}}
    Subject Knowledge/ Conceptual Clarity   &\ratings & \multirow{4}{4.5cm}{{\textbf{Any specific comments on trainer}} \newline\newline \mediumline  \newline\newline \mediumline \newline\newline  \mediumline\newline\newline  \mediumline \newline\newline  }\\ [2\baselineskip]
    Trainer Created and maintained an environment for learning &\ratings & \\[2\baselineskip]
    Rate the trainer's training skills and competency &\ratings &\\ [2\baselineskip]
    Would you like to attend other sessions by this trainer &\ratings &
    \\[2\baselineskip]

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ah, thats much more elegant. +1.